# How to get Buybox price from amazon using MWS or Product Advertising API?

Tags: amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

I want to get product Buybox price based on product ASIN.

Is there any API available in Amazon ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ItemLookup` call of the [Product Advertising API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemLookup.html) has a `ResponseGroup` named `Offers` which will allow you to get the buy box price (or, if nobody has the buy box, it will return the lowest offer).

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44080322/buy-box-amazon-product-advertising-api) it seems there is no way to tell if a returned price is actually the buy box price or just the lowest offer.

Alternatively, if you are a seller on Amazon, you could also use the `GetCompetitivePricingForSKU` call of the [MWS Products API](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html?ie=UTF8&section=products&group=products&version=latest).

Comment: To add to this, as I got stuck for a moment, if you want to get it reliably, make sure you do not set the `MerchantId` parameter. Having it set to `Amazon` will cause `Offers` to be empty on products that are sold only through independent sellers